# Does the go Azure AD MSAL library support PoP OAuth?

Tags: go, azure-ad-msal

Looking to support PoP OAuth via the Azure go sdk, and I was reading the feature request for PoP and SHR support here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/issues/439

Does the Azure go sdk today support PoP OAuth?

I haven't written code yet, but am exploring interfaces and the sdk to see how to do it.